# Creating a list of integers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

Is it possible to create a list of integers with a single line of code, without using any third-party libraries?

I tried with the syntax:

```
lst = list(int(1234))
```

or the syntax:

```
lst = list(int(1,2,3,4))
```

but both return an error.

Ideally i would like something like this:

```
>>> lst = list(int(input('insert numbers:  )))
insert numbers:  1234
>>> print(lst)
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Usually when i want to create a list with integers i do the (rather long) following:

```
lst = []
n = int(input('how many numbers?  '))
for i in range(n):
    num = int(input('number?  '))
    lst.append(num)
```

Comment: `list(map(int, input()))`?

Comment: `[int(n) for n in list(input())]`?

Comment: How about just `[1,2,3,4]`? (If you are at this level of understanding, it would be better if you just follow a tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals of Python.)

Comment: "why downvoting my question? It's obvious i'm a newby" Because Stack Overflow is not intended to be a tutorial resource; you are generally expected to understand the fundamentals of how to write code in the language you are using, and have a question about a specific *problem you are trying to solve* using those fundamentals. Also, nobody cares about your level of experience; questions stand on their own. This is *not a discussion forum* and thus talking about yourself (i.e. anything other than *the code or the related problem*) is off topic.

Comment: You haven't been linked to a duplicate question because it isn't clear exactly what your requirements are (and they appear to be somewhat flexible). Also, if there is an answer that you find acceptable, rather than editing your question to note this, you should *accept* it by clicking the check-mark icon next to it (an upvote doesn't hurt either). Please consider reviewing the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = input('insert numbers:  ')
lst = [int(d) for d in lst]
lst
```

As your comment, try only this one line:

```
[int(d) for d in input('insert numbers:  ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't perform this operation directly without passing to string type because int type is not iterable. In that case, you can just use input() without int().

You can try this 2 situations to create a list:

In this case, numbers without separation would be placed, such as 1234 (it would be more difficult to get numbers with more than 1 place, for example, 10, 11...)

```
test1 = input('insert numbers :')
lst = [int(number) for number in test1]
lst
```

In this way, you perform the separation using comma (',') for the numbers, like 1,12,13,5 and I think this is more appropriate because you can get all numbers.

```
test2 = input('insert numbers (separate with comma):')
lst = [int(number) for number in test2.split(',')]
lst
```